# iOS audio isInputAvailable is 1 but mChannelsPerFrame is 0

Tags: ios, audio, audio-recording

I have an iOS record project connect to untiy3d exported project, and the record can not work, I'm checked the microphone is ok, because `isInputAvailable` return 1, but the AudioQueueNewInput return error AudioQueueNewInput failed ('fmt?'), and found the `mChannelsPerFrame` is 0 I think this value should be `1`. how can I do fix this